# Finding the asymptotes of a hyperbola

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given the hyperbola $x^2/16$ - $y^2/9$   $ = 1$ what would the equation of the asymptotes be?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Any hyperbola of the form

$$\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}} - \frac{y^{2}}{b^{2}} = 1$$

has asymptotes given by the lines $$y = \pm \frac{b}{a} x$$

In your case, $a = \sqrt {16} = 4$, and $b = \sqrt{9} = 3$.

Comment: Votes have become so scarce! +1

Answer (score 1):

The asymptotes are

$$y=\pm\frac34x$$

Now your work is to *justify* why....